# Allowing external internet access through a proxy

Tags: devops, gcloud, vpn, squid

Setup:
Created VM A with squid proxy installed on an static external IP.
Created another VM B. This VM also has its own external static IP.

Now I want to restrict internet access on VM B and all calls from that VM should be proxied to VM A.

I have this setup in GCloud, what would be the best way to make this work.

I have referred a couple of articles on GCloud but most of the examples have this setup within a VPC network and that can be managed through the internal IPs.

Any recommendations on this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Change the route table on VM B to forward traffic to VM A. Notes: 1) this requires that VM A is correctly set up to route/forward traffic. 2) Not all traffic from VM B will be supported by the Squid Proxy (ICMP, DNS, etc). You must understand IP and Routing.

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley, I am currently working on this, will keep you posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I was able to find a solution for the problem I posted.
Here is what I did

I created two VMs

1. VM A with windows server OS
2. VM B with Linux OS and squid proxy installed

I had two setup firewall rules for both these VMs under VPC Network in GCloud

In VM A, I added a proxy setting in Windows to forward all calls to VM B 
In VM B, I updated the squid.conf to allow access to VM A and also to allow a set of websites that can be called from VM A and restricted all other websites.

Comment: Your solution does not restrict Internet traffic. Your solution enables the proxy of HTTP traffic which requires software to use the proxy settings. Systems with a public IP address can bypass the proxy by ignoring your proxy settings.

Comment: @JohnHanley, yes agreed, but I am thinking of applying firewall rules in GCloud to restrict access to internet, this is what we have done on one of our other tenants, does this sound good to you? do you foresee any problems?

Comment: Be careful setting egress rules unless you know exactly what they do, what they cannot do, and which services need access to which endpoints and the IP protocol they are using. In general, I do not recommend egress rules. You are only setting up an HTTP proxy. A virtual machine has (could have) many services that do not use HTTP such as DHCP, ICMP, DNS, NTP, etc. As I mentioned in my first comment to your question, routing is the correct implementation, not proxies. You will be putting bandaids on top of bandaids and spending a lot of time figuring out weird problems. Monitor all logs.